# Rails Console prevent assignment output to terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, rails-console

I have 500+ strings in a file. If I simply copy-paste it into Rails console to assign the values to an array, it takes a lot of time(10 mins+) and the CPU usage spikes to maximum (the fans go crazy in my laptop) just to print whatever I have pasted. How can I skip that from being printed on screen because I'm sure assignment (without echo) shouldn't take more than a minute.

Comment: Instead of copy&paste, read that file, e.g [File.foreach](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-foreach)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'File' class in ruby to read the file instead of just copy pasting.

```
File.open("path/to/your/file").each do |file|
  file.each_line do |line|
  dat_array = line.split()
end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an empty string after that.

```
my_str = "paste here";""
```

Or mute the irb echo by setting

```
conf.echo = false
```

Comment: The first one won't really work since my assignment string is really big and printing that during assignment itself takes a lot of time.